# Cannot find package within project directory

Tags: go

I've been trying to solve this problem for the past two hours. I cannot, for the life of me, understand how the folks who developed Go did such a fine job with the language but such a terrible job with package management.

Here is my `go env` output:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/<me>/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/<me>/Documents/Proj/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/opt/go/libexec"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/z4/b3lxy_51405_b8pb_680l4xh0000gn/T/go-build063693521=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Notice that my `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` are set.

Here is the structure of my go workspace (`/Users/<me>/Documents/Proj/go`):

```
go/
|-bin/
|-pkg/
|-src/
  |--github.com/
    |--user/
      |--myproject/
        |--client/
          |--client.go
        |--main.go
```

Here is my `client.go` file:

```
// client.go
package client

type MyClient struct {}
```

this is my `main.go` file:

```
// main.go
package main

import "client"

func main() {}
```

When I run `go build` in the project root, I get this error:

```
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "client" in any of:
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/transport (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/<me>/Documents/Proj/go/src/transport (from $GOPATH)
```

The first time this happened, I tried to correct the path above:

```
// main.go
package main

import "github.com/user/myproject/client"

func main() {}
```

Then I got this error:

```
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "client" in any of:
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/transport (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/<me>/Documents/Proj/go/src/github.com/user/myproject/transport (from $GOPATH)
```

Which is bizarre, since the package exists at that exact path.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Your second attempt is the correct one, using only `"client"` will look for such a package in `$GOPATH/src/client`. That said, I'm unsure why in both cases the error message mentions "transport" in the paths.. Is any of your code, that you haven't shared, referencing a "transport" package?

Comment: Please read "How to Write Go Code" carefully one more time. Then ask yourself why `import "client"` should work. That simply is not how import works with the go tool. Just stick to what "How to Write Go Code" tells you. Word for word.

Comment: Did you read the question @Volker? `github.com/user/myproject/client` threw an error.

Comment: I did and your question, the error(s) and your code do not make much sense if combined: They are inconsistent. And you have some strange Go installation. It is really up to _you_ to provide enough sound and consistent information so that _we_ can help you.

Comment: Dear Volker, can you explain what he is doing wrong? I think he is doing exactly as it should be done, but something else is wrong, which I explained in my answer. I wonder if you agree with this, please elaborate, we might all learn from that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not import `clien`t but which path is coming from `GOPATH/src`, in this particular case `github.com/user/myproject/client` because that is your path.

I see that the way you describe your problem is not exactly the way it is on your computer. You replaced some things. That is understandable, you do not want to tell the world how your computer looks like. So you replaced your name with "`<me>`".

You also replaced the projectname, with `MyProject` in your question, that is also, just like the user name, a potential spot for an error which we cannot see, because you replaced it. Never use long names in development-paths on Windows, because Windows is doing dirty tricks with them, sometimes.

I am sure there is something the matter which is a problem. Try using your short-directory name in the go-path. Check this: https://superuser.com/questions/1182040/strange-short-path-name-on-windows

Comment: Did you read my question? trying to import `github.com/user/myproject/client` threw an error

Comment: I edited my answer, so it will be better readable for others which land on this page.